# JS to add TARGET to form

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, target

I need to insert target="_top" into a < form>.  The form is being auto-generated, so I can't just code it in.  Is there some jquery or js I could use to add a target to a form?

The form's id is id='login_form' fyi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I don't know your form code, so I just fill the form width some simple markups.

and you can just simply write `$("#login_form").attr('target', '_top');`

live demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/bitsmix/HMxja/